# How could I access ManagedBean's property from Java class?

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I have a requestScope bean, regular Java bean, and Spring configuration just like the code shown below. May I know how can I access the bean's property from regular Java code that is configured with Spring?

**Managed Bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="requestBean")
public class RequestBean {
   private String theID;

   /** getter and setter of theID **/
}
```

**Spring Bean**

```
public class SpringBean {

   private RequestBean theBean = null;

   // how could I access the RequestBean.theID from this class ??
}
```

**Spring configuration**

```
<bean id="springBean" class="org.huahsin.SpringBean"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand the question, but I think it is simply by calling the getter:

```
public class SpringBean {

   private RequestBean theBean = null;

   ...
   public void aCallingMethod() {
      if (theBean != null) {
            theBean.getTheId();  // <-- here it is !!
      }

   }
}
```

**EDIT**

To inject the request bean into the Spring bean, either you use an @Autowired annotation:

```
public class SpringBean {

   @Autowired
   private RequestBean theBean = null;
   ...
}
```

Either you inject it in your XML file:

```
<bean id="springBean" class="org.huahsin.SpringBean">
     <property name="theBean" ref="requestBean"/>
</bean>
```